# Removing strings from a list dependent on their length?

Tags: python, string, list, loops, nested-lists

I am trying to remove any strings from this list of strings if their length is greater than 5. I don't know why it is only removing what seems to be random strings. Please help. The item for sublist part of the code just changes the list of lists, into a normal list of strings.

```
list2 = [['name'],['number'],['continue'],['stop'],['signify'],['tester'],['racer'],['stopping']]
li = [item for sublist in list2 for item in sublist]
var=0
for words in li:
if len(li[var])>5:
    li.pop()
var+=1
print(li)
```

The output is: `['name', 'number', 'continue', 'stop', 'signify']`

Comment: Why do you have every string contained in a sublist?

Comment: The result is random because you're removing things from a list at the same time you're iterating over it.  Don't do that.

Comment: Please check the code because it raises IndentationError.

Comment: Remember that li.pop() always remove the last value of the list unless you specified the position.

Answer (score 1):

Just include the check when flattening the list:

```py
list2 = [['name'],['number'],['continue'],['stop'],['signify'],['tester'],['racer'],['stopping']]
li = [item for sublist in list2 for item in sublist if len(item) <= 5]
```

```
['name', 'stop', 'racer']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to build a new list with only items that are 5 or less in length.

```
>>> l = ['123456', '123', '12345', '1', '1234567', '12', '1234567']
>>> l = [x for x in l if len(x) <= 5]
>>> l
['123', '12345', '1', '12']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
list(filter(lambda x: len(x[0]) <= 5, list2))
```